# Google App Engine Example of Uploading and Serving Arbitrary Files

Tags: google-app-engine

I'd like to use GAE to allow a few users to upload files and later retrieve them. Files will be relatively small (a few hundred KB), so just storing stuff as a blob should work. I haven't been able to find any examples of something like this. There are a few image uploading examples out there but I'd like to be able to store word documents, pdfs, tiffs, etc. Any ideas/pointers/links? Thanks!

Comment: Blobstore seems to be what you are looking for. Try send_blob() and its save_as option: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same logic used for image uploads apply for other archive types. To make the file downloadable, you add a `Content-Disposition` header so the user is prompted to download it. A webapp simple example:

```
class DownloadHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, file_id):
        # Files is a model.
        f = Files.get_by_id(file_id)
        if not f:
            return self.error(404)

        # Set headers to prompt for download.
        headers = self.response.headers
        headers['Content-Type'] = f.content_type or 'application/octet-stream'
        headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % f.filename

        # Add the file contents to the response.
        self.response.out.write(f.contents)
```

(untested code, but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use the Blobstore API.
You don't mention if you are using [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html) or [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html) so here are links to both.

Answer (score 2):

I use blobstore API that admits any file upload/download up to 50 MB.

Comment: You can upload 5GB instead of 50MB now. See here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits